# Can I put one type in a template as default value or null in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to develop a class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         if(T !=null)
         {
             // do some work
             T.report("I am here");
             // do some more work.
         }
     }
 }
```

and use it similar to this:

```
 class B
 {
    public:
          void report(std::string msg)
          {
              std::cout<<msg<<std::endl;
          }
}  

 main()
 {
      A<B> reportToStd;
      a<null> donotreport;
 }
```

So effectively if I am not defining a class to report, the object is not reporting back. The idea is to make it fast as I can pass a parameter to aach object saying to report or not. Also I don't want to have an empty class as this is messy.

Comment: Although in the nature of the question, your syntax is not correct. Please fix the fixable issues (Do you want a static member function, does A have a member T , should T passed as argument to DoSomething?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to explicitly instantiate the template class. Like so:

```
template<> class A<null_t>
{
     void DoSomething() { }
};
```

That way when the class is created with that template it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: thanks, How the class should be when it is created using a value? Can you please update your code?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Common {
  static void Before() { std::cout << "Before\n"; }
  static void After() { std::cout << "After\n"; }
};

template <typename T, typename Policy = Common>
struct A {
  A() {
    Common::Before();
    T::Report();
    Common::After();
  }
};

template <typename Policy>
struct A<nullptr_t, Policy> {
  A() {
    Common::Before();
    Common::After();
  }
};

struct Reporter {
  static void Report() {
    std::cout << "Reporter\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  A<nullptr_t> no_report;
  A<Reporter> do_report;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is good, but what if I need to do some work before and after calling report? If I use two class, then I need to copy my code into two place. See my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The template mechanism for doing the equivalent of `if ( T == null )` is template specialization.

Instead of using:

```
template <type T> class A
{
    public:

    void DoSomething()
    {
         if(T !=null)
         {
             T.report("I am here");
         }
     }
 };
```

You would use a helper class

```
template <type T> class A
{
    public:

    void DoSomething()
    {
        Reporter<T>::report();
    }
};
```

And implement `Reporter` as:

```
template <type T> struct Reporter
{
   static void report() {} // Do nothing is the default implementation.
};
```

and then specialize `Reporter` for `null`.

```
template <> struct Reporter<null>
{
   static void report() 
   {
      std::cout << "I am here" << std::endl;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use 'Duck Typing'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace Detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct has_report {
        private:
        template<typename U>
        static constexpr auto check(U*)
        -> decltype(std::declval<U>().report(std::declval<std::string>()), std::true_type());

        template<typename>
        static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

        public:
        typedef decltype(check<T>(0)) type;
    };
}

template <typename T> struct has_report : public Detail::has_report<T>::type {};

template <typename T>
class A
{
    private:
    template <typename U>
    void report(std::true_type, const U& u, const std::string& s) const
    {
        u.report(s);
    }

    template <typename U>
    void report(std::false_type, const U&, const std::string&) const
    {}

    public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        T t;
        // ...
        report(has_report<T>(), t, "I am here");
        // ...
    }
};

class B
{
    public:
    void report(std::string msg) const
    {
        std::cout<<msg<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A<B> reporting;
    A<std::nullptr_t> not_reporting;
    reporting.DoSomething();
    not_reporting.DoSomething();
}
```

With SFINAE in the helper structure 'has_report' you can determine if a type has a callable member function 'report(std::string)'. Than, call a reporting or non reporting function via tag dispatching.

(Compiled with g++ 4.8.2)